# Searching Binary files in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Is there any method to search content of binary files like PPT, PDF etc other than

converting it into X HTML format using xdmp:document-filter() function and searching on it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically no. You have to pull out the readable text out of the binary format to allow MarkLogic to index it. You can extract that text with `xdmp:document-filter()` or with functions like `xdmp:pdf-convert()` and `xdmp:word-convert()`, but there is no way to index binary nodes directly.

HTH!