# searching content in binary files using MarkLogic database

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to search binary files content, like PDF, using
MarkLogic with Node.js? How do you retrieve the PDF docs stored in database using MarkLogic with Node.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is not possible to search binary documents in the database - this stands true regardless whether you'd want to do this via Query Console or via any API.

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422599/searching-binary-files-in-marklogic) you can extract metadata for binary documents or convert binary documents into XML documents for example. Once you do that you can execute search against it and you can execute that search using Node.js as well of course.

Comment: There's a good chapter in the Application Developer's Guide regarding working with binaries: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/binaries